# Visitor's IP not getting forwarded in www-version of the domain

Tags: apache, ip, cpanel

I have a site where I am loading country-based dynamic contents. While Laravel's Request::ip() gets the proper(original) client IP if user visits the domain.com version, [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) version gets the same IP for all visitors. I suppose it's the NS resolver server somewhere or something I am not aware of.

Is there a way to set the www version with redirects or something else so that $_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gets the original client's IP? It's a Cpanel, so I don't have all the independence on all the DNS components to forward everything as per my need with custom Apache or Nginx setup. I just need a bypass, so to speak, if any.

Comment: If your cpanel is using nginx + apache you should ask your sysadmin to install [mod_remoteip](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051673894-How-to-enable-mod-remoteip). I know you want a bypass without asking them, but I doubt there is any.

Comment: Yes. I asked them already but they don't support it. I ended up redirecting the user to root domain, which I did earlier but wasn't working, hence the temporary bypass. Now redirecting started working. They fixed it. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Ask them how they fixed it and add an answer here to let the community to know it :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a bad setup if you allow clints to access a website with two different URLs i.e. www and non-www. This is because Google sees these as two different websites and logs stats for them separately. This is of course not ideal if you want good SEO. You should re-direct all clients to one URL, choose either www or non-www.

To achieve this you can create a redirect rule in your server configuration files.

Comment: I did so from Cpanel but it was not effective for some reason. That's why I was looking for a temporary workaround till they fix it. Seems like there isn't any. Redirection started working and it go fixed. Thanks btw.